# Hide Category in Forum Breadcrumb

Tags: php, forum

Is it possible to globaly hide the category-name in the Forum-Breadcrumb? `{include:breadcrumb}` includes the «Forum Home», Category, Forum and Title — but I wan't to get rid of the category.

What do I have to edit in the modules/forum-folder to delete the category from the breadcrumb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found it in the Code-Snippets in `mod.forum.php` starting at line ~1770 `// Is this a forum view?` AND the snippet starting at line ~1810 `// Is this the thread view?` … just delete or comment-out the code starting with:

```
$crumbs .= $this->_crumb_trail(
…
```

… where you find `forum_path('/viewcategory…` inside.

That's the crumb with the Category in it. If you comment-out the two, you don't have the Category anymore in the `/viewforum` and `/viewthread` views.

Search for other references if you want to get rid of it also on other views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible. I just looked at the default theme for the discussion module and in forum_breadcrumb > breadcrumb_trail.html there is the following code, which suggests to me that it's 100% dynamically generated. I know that there is no gui interface to turn on/off various aspects of breadcrumbs.

```
<a href="{crumb_link}">{crumb_title}</a><span class="breadcrumbspacer">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

You'll probably need to modify the actually php files for the dicussion module to remove the categories. The discussion module is notoriously difficult to theme and customize.

Comment: I know the discussion-module theming quite well. I know I have to edit the mod.forum.php or another file to achieve this goal … what I don't get is PHP … therefore I don't know what exactly do I have to edit.